# Doctrine2 + FOSRestbundle, format value before serializing

Tags: rest, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle

I have an Entity with a standard datetimetz field, which I serve via a REST interface implemented using FOSRestbundle.

As per the standard settings, this date is serialized as a string, e.g. "2014-07-05T09:53:45+0200".

Instead of this, I would like it to be served as a Unix timestamp (i.e. by using the standard getTimeStamp() function of PHPs DateTime class). However, I realized just now that either Doctrine2 or the Serializer never seem to access this field via its getter. Thus, it changes nothing at all if I have the following in my Entity definition:

```
public function getDate() {
    return $this->date->getTimestamp();
}
```

other than manually setting this field in the returned REST view, what would be a good way to make the appropriate conversion before serving it to the client?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JMSSerializer, use the [@Accessor](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#accessor) annotation.

```
class MyClass
{
    /*
     * @JMS\Accessor(getter="getTimestampDateTime")
     */
    private $datetime;

    public function getDatetime()
    {
        return $this->datetime;
    }

    public function getTimestampDateTime()
    {
        return $this->getDatetime()->getTimestamp();
    }
}
```

If you want to force the serializer to use public get/set, use the [@AccessType](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#accesstype) annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about if the [`@Type`](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#type) annotation was available in 2014,

But now, if you need to make a `DateTime` property serialised as **unix timestamp** :

```
/**
 * @JMS\Type("DateTime<'U'>")
 */
private $toTimestamp;
```